# Vue2.x how to use computed attribute in components?

Tags: vuejs2, vue.js

child component get the value from parent component，use `ref` in child component and the parent component use `$refs` to get the child component instance.But if child component get the parent component value `inputMessage` and computed , how to write ? the code :

```
export default{
    data(){
        return{
            parentMsg:'hello!'
        }
    },
    components:{
        child:{
            props:['inputMessage'],
            template:'<span>{{inputMessage}}</span>'
        },
        'child-secound':{
            props:['inputMessage'],
            template:'<span>{{lowerCase}}</span>',
            computed:{
                lowerCase(){
                    return this.$refs;
                    // return this.inputMessage.toLowerCase();
                }
            }    
        }

    },
}
```

I want child component get parent's value 'inputMessage' and use `this.inputMessage.toLowerCase();` to change it , but in there , `return this.$refs` is empty value , why? how to write ?

Comment: Why are you using `this.$refs`, shouldn't `return this.inputMessage.toLowerCase()` do the job?

Comment: @Saurabh yes , thank you , i first use `return this.inputMessage.toLowerCase() ` , but if doesn't work , so i chage it , beacuse i don't know in child component `this` means who , now i know it , thanks

Comment: Just add a prop to the child component to pass the value to it in the parent using a binding. Pretty standard. If it's a child a few levels down you should use an event hub or something like vuex